# How to increase the precision of NIntegrate to the highest level?

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to evaluate a numerical integration in my calculations. However, it seems that it can't return the correct answer (because I know the approximate answer). I think that it's a matter of precision according to the warnings that I get. So I tried to increase the precision by `WorkingPrecision`, `MaxRecursion` and `PrecisionGoal` (that have been suggested in MSE before) but they didn't address the problem. For this reason, I put my code here, hoping someone can help.

*A brief description of the code:* I first do a finite element calculation, then I define a new quantity using the results (which includes the integration in question), then I derive from the quantity and finally evaluate the result for a special point (here 5). The code returns `ComplexInfinity` while I know the approximate answer is around `-0.077`

```
     (* inputs *)
\[Mu] = 1836/1837.;
\[Omega] = 0.01;
m = 1836.;
M = 1. + m;
\[Gamma] = 1/2*M*\[Omega];
rMin = 10^-16;
rMax = 50.;
n = 20;
meshDisc = 0.001;
AP2 = 1.1251845019614726`;

(* numerical solution *)
V[r_] := -(1/r) + 1/2*\[Mu]*\[Omega]^2*r^2;
eqn = -(1/(2 \[Mu])) Laplacian[f[r], {r}] + V[r] *f[r];
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eqn, DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0., r <= rMin], 
    DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0., r >= rMax]}, f[r], {r, rMin, rMax},
    n, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> meshDisc}}}}] ;
ns = Position[vals, Min[vals]][[1, 1]];
Er = vals[[ns]];
fr = funs[[ns]];
funR[x_] := funR[x] = fr /. r -> x;

(* calculating the density *)
RhoPlus2[rp_?NumericQ] := ((2 \[Pi]*AP2)/(4 \[Gamma])) (M^2/(
    1 + m)) (Exp[-2 \[Gamma]*rp^2]/rp) NIntegrate[
    funR[r]^2/r*
     Exp[-((2 \[Gamma])/M^2) r^2] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma])/M) rp*r] - 
       Exp[-((4 \[Gamma])/M) rp*r]), {r, rMin, rMax}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 30];

(* derivations of density *)
Vk1P2[r_?NumericQ] := (D[D[RhoPlus2[r2], r2], 
       r2] + (2/r2) D[RhoPlus2[r2], r2])/RhoPlus2[r2] /. r2 -> r;
Vk2P2[r_?NumericQ] := (D[RhoPlus2[r2], r2]/RhoPlus2[r2])^2 /. r2 -> r;
VkinP2[r_?NumericQ] := -(1/(2*m)) ((1/2) Vk1P2[r] - (1/4) Vk2P2[r]);
VkinP2[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

The eigenfunctions coming from  `NDEigensystem` are defined according to `MachinePrecision`. Asking higher `WorkingPrecision` in `NIntegrate`is pointless.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider turning this into a fully fledged answer. In its current form it serves more as a comment rather than an answer.